# behavior of dynamically constructed function names in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, names

I have the following snippet defined in local scope of some function:

`let str = someString.replace(/(~\w+~)/g, match=>params[match](someValue));`

params is local object of that function too. Basically, params looks like this:

```
{
    "~idvP~": someValue=>{return someValue},
    "~dtv~": ()=>{return Date.now()},
    "~V~": ()=>{return someArray[someIndex(calculatedFromTheseValues)]}
}
```

The snippet works well in that particular function, successfully making the object, where some particular values of "someString" are being massively replaced by the snippet.

However, when I'm trying to use exactly the same snippet in a local scope of another - almost identical - function, I'm getting the following error - "**params[match] is not a function**": (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_function)

Despite such error message, typeof params[match], placed next to the snippet's line, returns that params[match] IS a function, hm.

Moreover, I was testing if full clones of the original snippet and the original params can be run where "almost identical" ones give me the error: the result was the same error, only from "successful in another place" code.

If I re-do the unsuccessful snippet using eval() function in the following way:

- I put `eval(params[match])` in place of `params[match](someValue)` expression. I.e. I get the following snippet in place of the original one:

`let str = someString.replace(/(~\w+~)/g, match=>eval(params[match]));`

- I swap declarations of values in params object from "arrow functions" to
  "strings", required by eval(). E.g. such declaration as:

`"~dtv~": ()=>{return Date.now()};`

I swap into

`"~dtv~": "Date.now()"`

Then under eval() and with these changes of values declarations in params object, my snippet starts working just fine. Only way slower, than my original snippet.

Any thoughts on what might cause - or not cause - the error in case of "no eval()" snippet?  Where exactly I shall be looking? Thanks!

*************--------Requested example is added from here--------**************

Wow, I'm not totally sure if the complete example is going to be easy, but let it be, thanks. These snippets are taken from a sample that might be found by this link - https://webequipage.com/, where 'DBEUV Assets' buttons open the second screen, where via Radio Buttons one may assess Values for each individual Title of particular Attribute, selected at the first screen. Values for those 2 screens are being prepared by functions shown below (they are called from 3 nested for loops)

Functions `addNewAttributeTo_D()` and `addNewTitleTo_D` use `eval()` and if I'm trying to change that into variant `without eval()` - the one that works fine at the last here `addNewValueTo_D()` function, I get mentioned error.

`///////// Here it goes the sample code //////////`

`var valuePrototypeIn_D = 
'{"_P":{"r":"","v":"~idvP~"},"a_i":{"r":"","v":"true"},"cb":{"r":"","v":"true"},"dtc":{"r":"","v":"~dtv~"},"dtd":{"r":"","v":""},"V":"~V~"}';`

`var titlePrototypeIn_D = // almost the same string as valuePrototype. It also includes valuePrototype`

`var attribPrototypeIn_D = // the same string as value and title Prototypes combined`

```
function make_D(whoRequested) //keeps spare parts for all 3 functions below
{
  switch (whoRequested) {
    case "addNewAttributeTo_D": return {
      "~idtD~": "_D.H.ID.v.replace(/[⟃⟄]/gu,'')",
      "~_$tn~": "1",
      "~_$vn~":"1",
      "~ltn~": "1",
      "~dta~": "Date.now()",
    }
    case "addNewTitleTo_D": return {
      "~idtP~": "aNum",
      "~_$vn~":"1",
      "~lvn~": "1",
      "~AT~": "$words[getRandomInt(1, $words.length)]",
      "~dtt~": "Date.now()"
    }
    case "addNewValueTo_D": return {
      "~idvP~": tNum=>{return tNum},
      "~dtv~": ()=>{return Date.now()},
      "~V~": ()=>{return $words[getRandomInt(1, $words.length)]}
    }
    break;
    default: cAlert(`Nothing was found by function ${arguments.callee.name} on request of features from ${whoRequested}!`);
  }
}
function addNewAttributeTo_D(aNum, tNum, vNum){// throws error "params[match] is not a function" if I try to change its version into "without eval()". Works fine with eval() though.
  let params = make_D(arguments.callee.name);
  let str = attribPrototypeIn_D.replace(/(~\w+~)/g,match=>eval(params[match]));
  _D.aL[aNum] = JSON.parse(str);
}

function addNewTitleTo_D(aNum, tNum, vNum){// throws error params[match] is not a function if I try to change it into "without eval()". Works fine with eval too.
  let params = make_D(arguments.callee.name);
  let str = titlePrototypeIn_D.replace(/(~\w+~)/g,match=>eval(params[match]));
  _D.aL[aNum][tNum] = JSON.parse(str);
  _D.aL[aNum].ltn.v = tNum;
}

function addNewValueTo_D(aNum, tNum, vNum){ //!!! no eval() here, but works fine
  let params = make_D(arguments.callee.name);
  let str = valuePrototypeIn_D.replace(/(~\w+~)/g,match=>params[match](tNum) );
  _D.aL[aNum][tNum][vNum] = JSON.parse(str);
  _D.aL[aNum][tNum].lvn.v = vNum;
}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)

Comment: That isn't a [mcve]. It seems to have a bunch of unneeded baggage, and isn't complete: It isn't possible to simply run that code to see the problem. You should use the Stack Snippets feature to include a live demo.

Comment: You are right, it takes a bunch of code to replicate the problem aside of my major development, since any simpler model JUST WORKS. "In short" I'm able to explain the problem only by words:

`params[match]()` construction that creates dynamically switched functions in one part of my code works fine, while in the other one - pretty similar - it throws `params[match] is not a function` error. Even though "dynamic code" that I'm "switching" looks like functions to me.

I have some fresh ideas on what I could be missing, I'm going to try them today.

Thanks for mentioning live demo!

Comment: I finally found what caused the problem, sorry for getting you involved.